# phonegap build windows phone from OSX

Tags: macos, cordova, windows-phone

Hei,
one question: is it possible to build/run/emulate a windows phone app on a OSX operating system?
i've tried it using phonegap

```
phonegap run wp8
```

bit I am getting the following error

```
Error loading cordova-wp8
```

I would (for now) just llike to know if it is possible at all or I have to change to another OS for building/developing the windows phone app?

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to do this is through virtualization software. It's the same way for Windows and iOS. You could also use a build service like Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible by **Virtualized Environment**

Yes, the Windows Phone 8 Simulator / Windows Phone 8 Emulator can run directly in OS X. However the mouse cursor is not visible. Mouse works, but no cursor/circle to show where your pointer is, which makes the VM difficult to use. [Windows Phone 8 Simulator does the same thing on Windows when launched in Hyper V Manager (rather than Visual Studio).](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/d9cbddc6-ed8e-43aa-80dd-19e1b5c2ca05/some-problems-using-windows-8-phone-emulator) This may change in future. Keyboard support is fine.

**I used VMware Fusion 6.01 / OS X Mavericks.**

[image]

- Get the Flash.vhd file from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd** inside Windows 8,
  and copy it to OS X (I used VMware Fusions Sharing feature to set
  this up quickly)
- Import the VM into VMware Fusion
- Change the CPU and Memory setting to a minimum of 2 cores, 512 MB
  (Windows Phone 8's mimum requirement). Before I did this, Windows
  Phone 8 would pause at the boot screen.

Windows Phone 8 will launch.

[Please Follow this tutorial for better Understandings.](http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2013/01/09/how-to-enable-wp8-emulator-on-mac/)

Comment: thanks Hassan,
unfortunately I am not allowed to install windows on my machine (licensing issues), so I'll need to switch to a windows computer for this task then. Thanks for sharing this nevertheless. may become handy in future